# how can i overwrite existing log file in inno setup

Tags: logging, installer, overwrite, logfiles

i am new to inno setup. I want logging information, for that I set SetupLogging=yes and I used following code for getting log file .

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
    var
 logfilepathname, logfilename, newfilepathname: string;

 begin
  logfilepathname := expandconstant('{log}');
  logfilename := ExtractFileName(logfilepathname);
  newfilepathname := expandconstant('{app}\') +logfilename;

  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    filecopy(logfilepathname, newfilepathname, false);
  end;
 end;
```

but as and when i install installer , it is generating a new log file with filenames as  Setup Log 2014-08-11 #001 ,Setup Log 2014-08-11 #002 and so on.

But i don't want multiple log files even if i run the installer multiple times.I want, Each time when i run it should overwrite existing log file itself. I mean there should be only one log file .How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes i got it. I just changed my script as follows :

```
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  logfilepathname, logfilename, newfilepathname: string;
  begin

  logfilepathname := expandconstant('{log}');

// logfilename := ExtractFileName(logfilepathname); 

// RenameFile(logfilename,'Setup_Log.log');

 newfilepathname := expandconstant('{app}\') +'Setup_Log.log'

 if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
     filecopy(logfilepathname, newfilepathname, false);
  end;

  end;
```

Comment: Stumbling over here lately I'd prefer `DeinitializeSetup` for copying the log file (did it exist in those days?). Didn't test, though, how that reacts on setup being aborted...